# How to update the props of a rendered react component from App.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component MoviesGallery.js with the following configuration:

```
class MoviesGallery extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { currentImage: 0 };
        this.closeLightbox = this.closeLightbox.bind(this);
        this.openLightbox = this.openLightbox.bind(this);
        this.gotoNext = this.gotoNext.bind(this);
        this.gotoPrevious = this.gotoPrevious.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({movies_genre: nextProps.movies_genre})
    }
```

I have rendered the component in my main App.js file like so:

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme)}>
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
          <RaisedButton primary={true} label="Query" className="header_buttons"/>
          <RaisedButton secondary={true} label="Reset" className="header_buttons"/>
        </header>
        <MoviesGallery/>
      </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to update the props of my MoviesGallery component without recreating the component. Since I already added the componentWillReceiveProps() to MoviesGallery component, how can I make it so when 'Query' button is clicked, it will pass new props to the **already rendered** MoviesGallery and componentWillReceiveProps() should cause it to re-render since the state will change.

Just confused about the function that will change the props themselves on-click of the rendered MoviesGallery component.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no way to change props *unless* you rerender it with new props - you can't mutate props. When the component is rerendered, `componentWillReceiveProps` is called.

Comment: How can I re-render it with new props on button click then?

Comment: you didn't post the render method of `MoviesGallery` but there is no need to set a local state when you are just using the props inside render. when a component receives a new prop it will call render again with the new prop.

Comment: @HasanJafri Do it in your parent. Accept a click handler prop in `MovieGallery` and pass an event handler to it. Then, in the event handler, set state in your parent, so that when the button is clicked, the parent's state is set. That state can be the new prop you want to pass to `MovieGallery`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a parent pass a new (value) prop to the child, the child component will call the render method automatically. There is no need to set a local state inside the child component to "store" the new prop.

Here is a small example of a `Counter` that receives a `count` prop and just displays it, while the parent `App` in this case will change the value in its state and pass the new value to `Counter`:

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { count } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>{count}</div>
    );
  }
}


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    }
  }

  onClick = () => {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  }


  render() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Counter count={count} />
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Add to counter</button>
      </div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the 'state' for your MovieGallery.js `props` because the `state` is an object that changes and you must your code like below :

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    query : null
  }
  myFunction(query){
     this.setState({query});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme)}>
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
          <RaisedButton primary={true} label="Query" className="header_buttons" onClick={this.myFunction = this.myfunction.bind(this)}/>
          <RaisedButton secondary={true} label="Reset" className="header_buttons"/>
        </header>
        <MoviesGallery newProps = {this.state.query}/>
      </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

i hope it helps